# Trying to sort worksheets in descending order based on cell values

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to sort worksheets based on a cell value located within each sheet. The main area I am having difficulty is applying the sort to ONLY selected sheets. Below is what I have so far. Pretty new to VBA

```
Sub SortWksByCell()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

  For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count
    For j = i + 1 To ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count
        If UCase(Worksheets(i).Range("q1")) <= _
          UCase(Worksheets(j).Range("q1")) Then
            Worksheets(j).Move Before:=Worksheets(i)
        End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What issue is not working, what issue are you getting?

Comment: `Worksheets(j)` isn't necessarily in `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets`. Why not iterate the `SelectedSheets` collection?

Comment: basically the issue is that it simply isnt sorting the selected sheets. and @Mat'sMug, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you `Move` a worksheet you loose the selection of worksheets, so you have to fix it before starting the sorting process

```
Option Explicit

 Sub SortWksByCell()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim wss As Sheets

    Set wss = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    For i = 1 To wss.Count
        For j = i + 1 To wss.Count
            If UCase(wss(i).Range("q1")) <= _
              UCase(wss(j).Range("q1")) Then
                wss(j).Move Before:=wss(i)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: that was much closer, but it still is sorting sheets that arent selected @user3598756

Comment: Yup, looks like it. Thanks!